# Data not found in Kendo React DropDownList

Tags: telerik, kendo-react-ui

i'm trying to figure out why my kendo react dropdownlist doesn't show any data

To be precise `NO DATA FOUND.` 
Below there is the snippet of code with the configuration of the dropdownlist

```
<DropDownList
data={countryList}
defaultValue={"Please select country"}
onChange={handleCountryChange}
/>
```

And there is the content oh `countryList` when i do a `console.log(countryList)`

```
0: "Afghanistan"
1: "Albania"
2: "Algeria"
3: "Andorra"
4: "Angola"
5: "Argentina"
6: "Armenia"
7: "Australia"
```

and so on for all the countries
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found the solution:

In `DropDownList` you have to include also:

 - `textFieled={"name"}`

 - `value={"admincode"}`

So I can resume that `textField` is the data that you want to display in the DropDown and `value` is the value of the corresponding `textField` element